# C# integer validation

Tags: c#, validation, while-loop

I have searched stackoverflow and haven't found anything that answers my question. Unfortunately it is not an easy question to word as a search query.

I'm using c# and I have a menu that asks the user to pick an option from 1 - 4. I am validation that the value picked is an integer, but my code breaks whenever I enter a letter or symbol. How do I add the validation for this to? My code currently is as follows.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
        FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();
        int mainMenuChoice=0;
        while ( mainMenuChoice != 1 || mainMenuChoice!= 2 || mainMenuChoice!= 3 || mainMenuChoice!= 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Full File Listing.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Filtered File Listing.");
            Console.WriteLine("3. FolderStatistics.");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Quit.");

            mainMenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (mainMenuChoice == 1)
            {
                Option1();
            }
            if (mainMenuChoice == 2)
            {
                Option2();
            }
            if (mainMenuChoice == 3)
            {
                Option3();
            }
            if (mainMenuChoice == 4)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you didnt enter a valid input! try again.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the reading from the command line to

```
if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mainMenuChoice))
{
    if (mainMenuChoice == 1)
        Option1();
    else if (mainMenuChoice == 2)
        Option2();
    else if (mainMenuChoice == 3)
        Option3();
    else if (mainMenuChoice == 4)
        Option4();
    else
        Console.WriteLine("you didnt enter a valid input! try again.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("you didnt enter a valid input! try again.");
}
```

and repeat the warning message for your user in the else part of the TryParse if.

[Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return false when the characters on the command line cannot be converted to an integer and assigned to the out parameter  `mainMenuChoice`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mainMenuChoice))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That's not a number!");
}
...
```

But in fact, you're never actually using the input *as* a number, so there's no real need to parse it. You could just leave it as a string:

```
bool retry;
do
{
    retry = false;
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Full File Listing.");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Filtered File Listing.");
    Console.WriteLine("3. FolderStatistics.");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Quit.");

    string mainMenuChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(mainMenuChoice)
    {
        case "1":
            Option1();
            break;
        case "2":
            Option2();
            break;
        case "3":
            Option3();
            break;
        case "4":
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid input! Try again.");
            retry = true;
            break;
    }
} while(retry);
```

Also, although this is pretty clear and easy to ready, you don't actually *need* the `retry` variable. Although it's a lot less obvious how this works (and I would probably avoid it for that reason), you can structure your loop like this:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Full File Listing.");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Filtered File Listing.");
    Console.WriteLine("3. FolderStatistics.");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Quit.");

    string mainMenuChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    switch(mainMenuChoice)
    {
        // same as above
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid input! Try again.");
            continue; // goes back to beginning of the loop
    }
    break; // exits the loop
} while(true);
```

Comment: i have tried putting that in, but it did not work. im not sure how any of that code works, so i wouldnt know where to begin trying to explain the error. i am quite new to this im afraid.

Comment: @user3158872 This would replace everything after `folderInfo.GetFiles()` in your `Main` method. What error message do you get?

Comment: @user3158872 See also [switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) for more information on this construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(true)
    {
        int menuChoice;
        string userInput = Console.Readline();
        if(Int32.TryParse(userInput, out menuChoice))
        {
            if(menuChoice >= 1 && menuChoice <= 4)
               RunCommand(menuChoice);
            else
               Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1-4");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("A number between 1-4 is required!");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the TryParse method on Int (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

For example:

```
int menuChoice;
if(!int.TryParse(Console.Readline(),out menuChoice){
   Console.WriteLine("The menu choice you made was invalid.");
} else {
   //do the rest of your code here
}
```